# Vizier HyperParameter Tuning Jobs Terminated by Service

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-ml

I am running a Vizier HyperParameter Tuning job on the GCP AI Platform and trials keep getting interrupted with the error: `Terminated by service. If the job is supposed to continue running, it will be restarted on other VM shortly.`

I am using a STANDARD_P100 GPU and it seems like the individual tuning trials are getting booted (pre-empted) from the GPU in the middle of training -- some trials complete successfully and some trials get stopped around 1000 or 2000 steps -- these are always happening on the 1000 which is significant because I am doing evaluation every 1000 steps so something seems to be happening when switching between training and evaluation that is allowing these jobs to get pre-empted. The next trial starts up and then typically runs for 1000 steps again (rather than restarting the previous trial).

Is there anything that I can do so that my trials will complete successfully? They never get re-started as the VM says and it seems like it makes the entire hyperparameter tuning worthless because ~90% of the trials are never completed and the ones that fail likely give bad information to the vizier optimization algorithm. These runs can be quite expensive to run on GPUs and they are essentially worthless as currently configured even though I am being charged for trials that don't ever complete.

An example of my hptuning_config is below...

```
scaleTier: CUSTOM
  masterType: standard_v100
  hyperparameters:
    goal: MAXIMIZE
    hyperparameterMetricTag: 'accuracy'
    maxTrials: 80
    maxParallelTrials: 1
    enableTrialEarlyStopping: TRUE
    params: ...
```

Answer (score 0):

I got the same problem. I suspect it's because of the `enableTrialEarlyStopping`

https://cloud.google.com/ml-engine/docs/using-hyperparameter-tuning#stopping_trials_early

You have to set:

```
enableTrialEarlyStopping: False
```